# CRM 2011 oData distinct

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, odata

is it possible to query using REST endpoint (oData query) and distinct the result

or maybe are there any syntax for the oData query for distinct in CRM 2011 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OData protocol doesn't support the distinct operator. Check [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839073/select-distinct-values-with-odata) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3867365/can-i-perform-a-distinct-with-a-wcf-data-service-odata-query).
The solution is probably retrieving data and filtering on client side.